# check constraint not getting set when i set for another column from same table and how to use arithmetic function in default constraint?

Tags: sql-server

I try to create table as follows with check and default constraints but it's getting error

```
create table book_issue_details
(
  s_id int foreign key references students(s_id), 
  book_id int foreign key references books(book_id), 
  issued_date date default (getdate()), 
  for_days int, 
  penalty float check(cast(for_days as float)>7), 
  payed float, 
  balance float default(penalty-payed)
);
```

but I am getting error as follows:

> Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 The name "penalty" is not permitted
>   in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant
>   expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not
>   permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is giving you the answer here:

> Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) >variables. **Column names are not permitted.**

Emphasis mine.

I assume what you *actually* want here is a computed column, as if the value of `penalty` or `payed` changed I *assume* you want the value of `balance` to change too.

The syntax for that would instead be:

```
balance AS penalty-payed PERSISTED
```

I have used `PERSISTED`, as I *assume* you'll want to query against it. making the column `PERSISTED` will mean that the Data Engine doesn't need to calculate the value whenever you query the table, and also means you can index the column (if you need to).

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a default column value as an expression or as another column. You have several workarounds:

- Use a computed column. You won't be able to update the column directly and you will be forcing it's value to it's expression. Instead of `balance float default(penalty-payed)`, use `balance AS penalty-payed`
- Use a view that shows this value if it's `NULL` (or the value you want) on the underlying table.
- Use an after insert/update trigger to set this value if it wasn't supplied.